# Appcelerator SQLite Like Operator syntax

Tags: sqlite, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using appcelerator and working with appcelerator studio, however I'm confused of using the like operator in query string in appcelerator

```
 values = Alloy.Globals.database_file.execute('select ChapterID,ChapterCode,ChapterName,ChapterOwner,ChapterOrder,ChapterDescription,ChapterNote,ParentChapterID from CbahiHSChapters like "%' searchText '%"');
```

quotes are placed incorrect.

Comment: See [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#double_quoted_string_literals_are_accepted). Though any time you insert a user-supplied string directly in a query instead of binding it to a parameter, you open yourself up for a world of hurt even when using normal single quoted strings.

Comment: I referred the document thank you, however how should I apply this in this query ? with double quotes "this is a legal SQL column name" and with single quote
'this is an SQL string literal'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine but you are missing `+` signs like this and where condition

```
values = Alloy.Globals.database_file.execute('select ChapterID,ChapterCode,ChapterName,ChapterOwner,ChapterOrder,ChapterDescription,ChapterNote,ParentChapterID from CbahiHSChapters where like "%' + searchText + '%"');
```

Comment: I tried with + sign as well but it gives syntax error.

Comment: it runs fine for me but I don't have your global db.exec. So perhaps the error is there and not the call itself? For a insert I'll call it like this: `db.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO db (name) VALUES (?)", item.name);` so the parameters follow the select code

Comment: Yes sir all the other queries works for me but only the 'LIKE' operator query is not working and gives syntax error.

Comment: But you know that your SQL syntax is missing a WHERE? I use it like this without any errors: `str = "word"; filter = " WHERE db.name LIKE '%"+ test +"%'"; var rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM db LEFT JOIN otherDb ON db.id = otherDb.id ' + filter + ' ORDER BY db.name');`

Comment: my bad thank you so much - I missed where condition